# Detecting checkbox touch

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

What method is to be used in order to detect whether a checkbox was touched by a user to change the `isChecked` status in my windows phone app? In my code I manually set a checkbox on start up and the callback gets fired right away, while I only want to fire the callback if the user interacted with the view.

```
public CheckBoxPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AvailableCheckBox.IsChecked = true; //name of the checkbox
    }
  private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)//event handler
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Changed");
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you have now?

Comment: Why not put IsChecked in the XAML? Don't think it will get raised then.

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder I set 1 of 3 checkboxes to checked depending on a value received from a server response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a variable to keep track of whether the page is loaded or not and only have the handler do stuff if it's loaded.

```
private bool _isLoaded = false;

public CheckBoxPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    AvailableCheckBox.IsChecked = true;

    _isLoaded = true; // enable the AvailableCheckBox_Checked handler
}

void AvailableCheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_isLoaded) return; // stop here if not loaded yet

    // everything is loaded so let's execute some stuff
    MessageBox.Show("Changed");
}
```

Comment: Decided to go with this since I declared my eventhandlers from the XAML file.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Click method:

```
private void AvailableCheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (AvailableCheckBox.IsChecked == true)
    {
        // Checked
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the handler after you've decided if the Checkbox should be checked.

```
public CheckBoxPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    AvailableCheckBox.IsChecked = true;

    AvailableCheckBox.Checked += AvailableCheckBox_Checked;
}

void AvailableCheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Changed");
}
```